# Relationship between StorageClass, Persistent Volume and Persistent Volume Claims?

Tags: kubernetes

As I research, I know that the relationship between the PV and the PVC is one to one. How about the StorageClass, can one StorageClass can be mapped to multiple couple PV + PVC ?

Answer (score 1):

Persistent Volume — low level representation of a storage volume.
Persistent Volume Claim — binding between a Pod and Persistent Volume.
Storage Class — allows for dynamic provisioning of Persistent Volumes.

A StorageClass provides a way for administrators to describe the "classes" of storage they offer. Different classes might map to quality-of-service levels, or to backup policies, or to arbitrary policies determined by the cluster administrators. Kubernetes itself is unopinionated about what classes represent. This concept is sometimes called "profiles" in other storage systems

Storage Classes (SC)
StorageClass allows dynamic provisioning of Persistent Volumes, when PVC claims it.
StorageClass abstracts underlying storage provider.
StorageClass is used in conjunction with PVC that allow Pods to dynamically request a new storage.
StorageClass use provisioners that are specific to the storage platform or cloud provider to give Kubernetes access to the physical storage.
Each storage backend has own provisioner. Storage Backend is defined in the StorageClass component via provisioner attribute.